# How do you skip a string on an read-in file to get the float that follows after?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to read in a given file, the file is composed of different attributes that I am to give "workers" of a class, these attributes are given by the name of the attribute then a float number associated with the worker, ie: Fabrication     .25
Servicing     .45
Diagnostics    .65

I'm trying to use the scanner to retrieve just the float but am getting an exception error when attempting to use s.nextFloat(); I'm unsure how to split the entire string so that I am able to return just the value of the float.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Worker
{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
           // File text = new File("Workers.txt");
            //Creating Scanner instance to read File in Java
            //File text = new File("Workers.txt");



            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Workers.txt"));
            TheWorker one = new TheWorker(s);

            System.out.println(one.Fab);

            s.close();  
        }   
}

class TheWorker
{
    String workername;
    String type;
    String CanWork = "Any";
    float hourlyRate;
    float Fab;
    float Serv;
    float Diag;
    float Trans;
    float Intake;
    float BW;
    float Paint;
    boolean working;

    public TheWorker(Scanner s) 
    {
        workername = s.nextLine();
        String type = s.next();
        if(type != "Full-Time")
        {
            String temp = s.next();
            if (temp.charAt(0) == '(')
            {
                CanWork = temp.substring(1,temp.length()-1);
                temp = s.next();
            }
            hourlyRate = Float.parseFloat(temp);
        }
        Fab = s.nextFloat();
        Serv = s.nextFloat();
        Diag = s.nextFloat();
        Trans = s.nextFloat();
        Intake = s.nextFloat();
        BW = s.nextFloat();
        Paint = s.nextFloat();  

    }


    TheWorker(String workername, String type, String CanWork, float hourlyRate, float Fab, float Serv, float Diag, float Trans, float Intake, float BW, float Paint, boolean working)
    {
        this.workername = workername;
        this.type = type;
        this.CanWork = CanWork;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        this.Fab = Fab;
        this.Serv = Serv;
        this.Diag = Diag;
        this.Trans = Trans;
        this.Intake = Intake;
        this.BW = BW;
        this.Paint = Paint;
        this.working = working;
    }
}

====Snippet from Workers.txt===
Eikichi Onizuka
Part-Time (Afternoon) 8.00 phr
Fabrication         .35
Service/Mechanics   .25 
Diagnostics         .25
Brake/Transmission  .25
Intake/Exhaust      .15
Body Work           .25
Paint/Finish        .45

Yusuke Urameshi
Part-Time (Afternoon) 7.60 phr
Fabrication         .35
Service/Mechanics   .55 
Diagnostics         .05
Brake/Transmission  .35
Intake/Exhaust      .45
Body Work           .15
Paint/Finish        .15




Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at TheWorker.<init>(Worker.java:60)`enter code here`
    at Worker.main(Worker.java:18)
```

Comment: So, you say you have multiple lines in the style of "a string ...... a float" ... and your code now reads one whole line, a single String and then seven floating point numbers. I'd might be wrong, but this can't be further away from your actual text file structure. Please also read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/513832)

Comment: It reads:
Fabrication     .25
Diagnostics    .65
Servicing     .85
it's the name of the attribute followed by a float, then the next line is again, name of the attribute followed by a float and so on.
i'm unable to show it in the comments as it doesn't allow me to skip to the next line using the enter key.

Comment: I'm trying to return just the float values to the given attributes, but when compiled I'm given the exception error, as i'm asking for s.nextFloat(); but the file is returning a string instead.

Comment: *i'm unable to show it in the comments* - Please show the format/example of your input as prt of your question

Comment: Those Strings like "Fabrication" or "Diagnostics" are in the file and need to be read, before trying to read the next float. And your exception is not from `nextFloat`, it is from `Float.parseFloat(temp)` from inside the `if(type != "Full-Time")` and to be honest, I don't see how `temp` could end up being empty in there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add sample text from the file you are reading: _Workers.txt_

Comment: Added part of the of the Workers.txt file being read into the program.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  There is nowhere is this file where there is a change to read 7 consequetive `float` values

Comment: And I know that string has to be read before reaching the float following, but I am unsure as to how to go about splitting the entire string line so that I can use just the float so that I may pass it back to the variable.

Comment: I'm essentially wanting to pull the float values out of each subsequent string line so that I can pass that value back as just a float. The workers.txt file gives the values of the attributes, but for the program, I just need the values of those attributes as I know which one goes where, so that I may return them to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your input file, you should be doing

1. Read Line for name
2. Read line and split for `Part-Time (Afternoon)` `8.00` `phr` - only arr[1] is a float
3. Read line X 7 times, splitting each for `Fabrication` `.35` again only arr[1] is a float

See [String::split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the exercise is to create a collection of `Worker` objects from a text file.

First let's see how to read a text file using the `Scanner` class. Class `Scanner` has a constructor that takes a [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). But `Path` is an interface, so you need to use class [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) to create an appropriate `Path`.

```java
Path p = Paths.get("Workers.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(p);
```

Now you can use the `Scanner` to read the file line by line.

```java
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
}
```

That's basically all the code required to read the file.
Now you want to use the data from the file to create `Worker` objects.
I'll assume that the file has the same format as the sample you posted, i.e. each "worker" details takes up exactly nine lines where the first line is the worker's name and an empty line separates each "worker". Each line needs its own, special handling, so I'll manage a `counter` variable to tell me which worker detail I have just read. And when I read an empty line, I know I have all the details for a single "worker".

Furthermore I will store all the `Worker` objects I create in a collection, a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to be precise.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Worker {
    private String workername;
    private String type;
    private String canWork = "Any";
    private float hourlyRate;
    private float fab;
    private float serv;
    private float diag;
    private float trans;
    private float intake;
    private float bw;
    private float paint;
    private boolean working;

    // Constructor
    public Worker(String workername,
                  String type,
                  String canWork,
                  float hourlyRate,
                  float fab,
                  float serv,
                  float diag,
                  float trans,
                  float intake,
                  float bw,
                  float paint,
                  boolean working) {
        this.workername = workername;
        this.type = type;
        this.canWork = canWork;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        this.fab = fab;
        this.serv = serv;
        this.diag = diag;
        this.trans = trans;
        this.intake = intake;
        this.bw = bw;
        this.paint = paint;
        this.working = working;
    }

    // Overrides method in class java.lang.Object
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s (%s) %.2f phr: Fabrication: %.2f, Service: %.2f, Diagnostics = %.2f, Transmission = %.2f, Intake = %.2f, Body Work = %.2f, Paint = %.2f",
                             workername,
                             type,
                             canWork,
                             hourlyRate,
                             fab,
                             serv,
                             diag,
                             trans,
                             intake,
                             bw,
                             paint);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path p = Paths.get("Workers.txt");

        // try-with-resources to automatically close the Scanner
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(p)) {
            List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
            int counter = 0;
            String workerName = null;
            String type = null;
            String canWork = null;
            float hourlyRate = 0.0f;
            float fab = 0.0f;
            float serv = 0.0f;
            float diag = 0.0f;
            float trans = 0.0f;
            float intake = 0.0f;
            float bw = 0.0f;
            float paint = 0.0f;
            String[] parts;
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                if (line.length() == 0) {
                    Worker aWorker = new Worker(workerName,
                                                type,
                                                canWork,
                                                hourlyRate,
                                                fab,
                                                serv,
                                                diag,
                                                trans,
                                                intake,
                                                bw,
                                                paint,
                                                true);
                    System.out.printf("%n%s%n", aWorker);
                    workers.add(aWorker);
                    workerName = null;
                    type = null;
                    canWork = null;
                    hourlyRate = 0.0f;
                    fab = 0.0f;
                    serv = 0.0f;
                    diag = 0.0f;
                    trans = 0.0f;
                    intake = 0.0f;
                    bw = 0.0f;
                    paint = 0.0f;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else {
                    counter++;
                    switch (counter) {
                        case 1:
                            workerName = line;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            parts = line.split(" ");
                            if (parts.length > 0) {
                                type = parts[0];
                            }
                            if (parts.length > 1) {
                                canWork = parts[1].substring(1, parts[1].length() - 1);
                            }
                            if (parts.length > 2) {
                                hourlyRate = Float.parseFloat(parts[2]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            fab = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            serv = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            diag = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            trans = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            intake = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            bw = Float.parseFloat(parts[2]);
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            parts = line.split("\\s+");
                            paint = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Unexpected: " + counter);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // Make sure we add the last "worker" in the file to our list.
            if (counter > 0) {
                Worker aWorker = new Worker(workerName,
                                            type,
                                            canWork,
                                            hourlyRate,
                                            fab,
                                            serv,
                                            diag,
                                            trans,
                                            intake,
                                            bw,
                                            paint,
                                            true);
                System.out.printf("%n%s%n", aWorker);
                workers.add(aWorker);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```